# Как подключить стили из родительской темы в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Решил делать дочернюю тему на основе темы indreams. Сделал все первые шаги для создания дочерней темы:

1. Создал папку с именем дочерней темы "indreams-child".
2. В ней добавил файл style.css со следующим содержанием:

   ```
   /*
   Theme Name: Дочерняя тема indreams
   Template: indreams
   */

   // импортируем стили родительской темы
   @import url("../indreams/style.css");

   // Свои дополнительные стили
   .foo{ color:red; }
   ```

Тема, по идеи уже должна работать. Но когда я активирую её и открываю, то вёрстка слетает!
Я прочитал в одной из статей в Интернете, что нужно создать в этой же папке файл                function.php и подключить в нём родительские стили. Я сделал это так:

```
function indreams_child_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() ); 
wp_enqueue_style( 'indreams-Arvo', indreams_font_url(), array(), null );
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-flexslider-css', get_template_directory_uri() .       '/css/flexslider.css');
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-font-awesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css');
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-superfish-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/superfish.css');
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-animate-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css');
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-prettyPhoto-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/prettyPhoto.css');
wp_enqueue_style('indreams-meanmenu-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/meanmenu.css');  
}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'indreams_child_enqueue_styles' );
```

Ничего снова не работает. Пожалуйста, помогите. Подскажите в чём проблема

*Примечание:* Точно такая же проблема и в других темах. Проблема исчезает, когда я весь тег head, сгенерированный в родительской теме, копирую в мою дочернюю.

Comment: А все ссылки прописаны правильно и нужные файлы подгражаются? Можно посмотреть в FireBug или другой отлаочной консоли, что нет 404-ых ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что я неправильно назвал файл functions.php!
Function.php вместо functions.php

Спасибо за комментарий, **newman**!